# Make DB tables customizable from an Admin

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance

I want to build an commercial product promotional mobile application in which the administrator of the app will be able to customize some texts / pictures or whatever from the database that dynamically populates the application.

> **For example:**
>
> > Lets assume that the database has a description and a picture for the
> >     product XYZ. The administrator of the **specific instance of the app**
> >     decides to change the description of the product through the provided
> >     CMS for ONLY this instance of the app.

The application will run on tablets that the users will be able to use inside a store, so the administrator of each instance of the app will be the store owner or someone that works there. All the texts / pictures that appear to the application will be fetched from the database.

The application will support both customers login and administrator login. I mean that if the admin of a specific store changes the content of a customizable DB table, all the users that login from this instance of the app will see the customized content.

How is this possible? I first thought to COPY the table that i want to be customizable every time a ADMIN is registed and have a foreign key pointing to the administrator from admin table. Is this an acceptable solution?

PS. I use mysql.

Comment: Make a column to designate which "instance" each row of data belongs to.

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit more on this?

Comment: Will there be ONE database instance with many clients adding things to it?  Or does each customer had his own database tables, plus add-ons?

Comment: I prefer one database.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be in the business of constantly dynamically creating a separate table for each store's admin to store their own data in. Instead, use a single table and designate a column to differentiate the admin's customization, organized by store.

You haven't given enough details to get into the minutiae of the implementation, but this approach can facilitate having users only see/edit data from their store with a view, stored procedures, etc. once you associate each employee and inventory item to a specific store.

```
  Inventory
  ---------
  Image
  Description
  Price
  Store

  Employee
  ---------
  Name
  Store
  Title
  StartDate
```

Comment: Let me try to give some more details about my implementation:
Each store is going to have the application running, advertising some products. The store manager will be able to change some of these product's properties. These changes will be visible ONLY at the store's application instance. The application will come out-of-the-box populated with products. I still do not get 100% your approach, although thank you very much for your help

Comment: Do you mean that each item the admin wants to changes will be entered to a new table with the store's name in the store column? Then the app will fetch all products from the general Products table and if an item has been customized the app will replace these products with the customized products table?

Comment: @john No, there is a single table for all products for all stores. When the app queries the inventory table, it only asks for products for that particular store `(WHERE STORE = "LocationA")`- which you know since the current user has LocationA attached to their Employee table row.

Comment: Sorry for my noobie questions, what if a product is in all the stores (A,B,C,D for example) ?

Comment: Then there is a row for ProductX in store A, a row for store B, etc. and each row is customized by the admin for each store.

Comment: So where the Customized product properties will reside?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, I will try to sketch a simple database schema. I will put the properties that could being customized by the store administrator into different tables from the "immutable" properties.

product table contains "immutable" property attributes:

```
+----+--------------+
| id | UPC          |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | product ABC  |
|  2 | product DEF  |
+----+--------------+
```

general_description table contains "default" description of product:

```
+----+------------+----------------------------+
| id | product_id | description                |
+----+------------+----------------------------+
|  1 |          1 | default description of ABC |
|  2 |          2 | default description of DEF |
+----+------------+----------------------------+
```

store_description table contains the product description customized by store administrator:

```
+----+------------+----------+-------------------------------+
| id | product_id | store_id | description                   |
+----+------------+----------+-------------------------------+
|  1 |          1 |        1 | description of ABCD by store 1|
+----+------------+----------+-------------------------------+
```

store table contains the information of store

```
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | store 1  |
|  2 | store 2  |
+----+----------+
```

So to get list of product with description for store 1:

```
select p.*, gd.description as 'general description', sd.description as 'store_description'
from product p
inner join general_description gd on p.id = gd.product_id
left join store_description sd on p.id = sd.product_id  and sd.store_id = 1 ;

+----+--------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
| id | UPC          | general description      | store_description             |
+----+--------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  1 | product ABC  | default description ABC  | descripiton of ABCD by store 1|
|  2 | product DEF  | general description DEF  | NULL                          |
+----+--------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Notice it is possible to use one table for product description. I have used two for clarity.

Comment: That's how, more or less, I had thought to implement it. Although I am not sure if this is the optimal solution.